# Mutual Information Estimation for Deep Learning

Tags: neural-networks, information-theory, mutual-information

What approaches do exist to estimate mutual information from data? I'm particularly interested
in techniques that could be applicable to deep learning scenarios, i.e., scenarios involving possibly hundreds of thousands of high dimensional data.

Comment: More details are needed. Mutual information between what variables? What's known about them? What do you want to use it for, and how is deep learning involved?

Comment: Have a look at the paper [MINE: Mutual Information Neural Estimation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04062).